# How to remove double sided foam tape from wall

Tags: home

Is there any better way to remove double sided foam tape from my wall, when i try to remove it form my wall it leave spots on the wall, is there any home remedy to remove these spots from my wall.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the experience that a combination of two actions leaves the best results:

1. I first use a hairdryer to bring up the temperature of the glue and then slowly remove the double sided tape from the wall
2. I then use a mixture of water and (clear) vinegar (4:1) to wipe away remaining stains of glue

Edit: there are also products like "Goo Gone" and "Goof Off FG650" which according to my neighbour work miracles on any remaining glue.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with removing foam tape:

- Pieces of the tape or the "stickum" are left on the surface, or sometimes some of the adhesive even migrates *into* wallpaper or paint. **Gentle** cleaning with a mild solvent, such as [naphtha paint thinner](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Klean-Strip-1-pt-Paint-Thinner-PA12779/203713853), followed by air drying and a final **gentle** cleanup with [eraser crumbs in a bag](http://www.draftingsteals.com/catalog-pencil-sharpeners---erasing-supplies-draftman-s-cleaning-pads.html) may work. Use caution -- paint thinner is **quite flammable**, so keep it away from any source of ignition. Test the solvent in an inconspicuous spot *before* cleaning the residue, since naphtha (mineral spirits) may damage paint or wallpaper.
- The spots may be areas where the paint or wall covering has been pulled off. In that case, the only option is to repair the damage: paint over the spot, or [patch the wallpaper with a piece with the same pattern](http://www.dummies.com/home-garden/walls-ceilings/how-to-patch-wallpaper/#slide-1). Because paint or patch is newer than that on the wall, there may be a slight mismatch that should disappear with time.